# how to use the ADO library variable values in custom powershell script in a yaml file

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to know how to use the variable values from the Azure DevOps library variable groups in a custom PowerShell script.

See my `.yaml` file shown here, where I would like to reference the variables within my PowerShell script. I want to achieve this with variables instead of variables.

```
parameters:
  - name: Name1
    displayName: 'Name1'
    type: string
    values: 
     - test01

  - name: Names2
    displayName: 'Name2'
    type: string
    values: 
     - rgp01
     - rgp02
     - rgp03

variables:
- group: poctest

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: 'pwsh/connection.ps1'
    arguments: |
      -Name1 ${{ parameters.Name1 }}
      -Name2 ${{ parameters.Name2 }}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, make sure your variable group exists, and has the variables you are trying to reference:

[image: Variable Group picture]

Reference the variable group in yaml using:

```
variables:
- group: my-variable-group
```

See full yaml using and referencing a variable in a variable group:

```
variables:
- group: my-variable-group

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: 'variable-print-test.ps1'
    arguments: >
      -Name1 $(VariableInGroup)
```

Build output:

[image: build output picture]

Read more on using variable groups in [Microsoft documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Here is my powershell script. You will also need to include the variab;e as a parameter:

```
param (
    [string]$Name1
)

Write-Host $Name1
```

---

### How to do this without using a PowerShell param

Instead of parsing the variable as an argument to the PowerShell script, you can map the variable to the process's environment like so:

```
variables:
- group: my-variable-group

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  env: 
    VariableInGroupEnv: $(VariableInGroup)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: 'variable-print-test.ps1'
```

and then reference the variable in Powershell using `$env:VariableInGroupEnv`.

Comment: Thank for the update . but when we pass the value in side the arguments dont we need to declare parameters in powershell script ?

Comment: Yes you will. I have updated my answer

Comment: I want to limit the parameters! with out having parameter any option to pass the values to script.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have added more detail to my answer on how you can do this without PowerShell parameters. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks it helps ! working as expected

Comment: Do you have idea about Schedule based pipeline trigger . can you help on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77902993/how-to-configure-the-schedule-condition-for-stage-in-yaml