# How to configure the schedule condition for stage in yaml

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to add conditions in stages for trigger the schedule based execution. I have created a variable group called poctest in Library with multiple values , based on that values i want to create the conditions under stage. based on that value when it trigger parameter value should satisfy the condition.  here is the YAML structure.

```
parameters:
  - name: Name1
    displayName: 'Name1'
    type: string
    values: 
     - test01

  - name: Names2
    displayName: 'Name2'
    type: string
    values: 
     - rgp01
     - rgp02
     - rgp03

variables:
- group: poctest
schedules:
- cron: '0 22 * * *'
  displayName: Schedule for the runbook execution 
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

stages:
Conditions: <How to call the variable group values, based on this values script arguments suppose to pass > 
- stage: FirewallManage 
   jobs:
   - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
       targetType: 'filePath'
       filePath: 'pwsh/connection.ps1'
       arguments: |
         -Name1 ${{ parameters.Name1 }}
         -Name2 ${{ parameters.Name2 }}
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail exactly what you're trying to accomplish and why. You can't schedule stages, you can schedule the entire pipeline. And you can't drive the schedule from a variable group; the schedule has to be fixed.

Comment: yeah sure ! basically in that variable group we have certain value , that values we need to pass as argument in execution . 
 for example in that variable group i have two values like subscription  : azuresb01 and resource : rgp01 , so when pipeline start auto trigger this value should replace the argument in powershell script

Comment: or in simple how to create schedule in yaml pipeline , while triggering need to pass some value s to parameter  so that script will run . in script certain parameters are there

Answer (score 0):

I have coded a sample code with `stage condition` following below scenarios

1. `condition` with static variables
2. `condition` with variable group

`azure-pipelines.yml`

```
parameters:
- name: param1
  type: string
  default: param1value

variables: 
- name: key1
  value: value1
- group: vgtest

stages:

- stage: StageA
  condition: eq(variables.key1, 'value1')
  jobs:
  - job: JobA
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'filePath'
        filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test.ps1
        arguments: > # Use this to avoid newline characters in multiline string
          -Input1 $(key1)
          -Input2 $(wbKey)
          -Input3 ${{ parameters.param1 }}
      displayName: 'condition pattern 1'

- ${{ if eq(variables.key1, 'value1') }}:
  - stage: StageB
    jobs:
    - job: JobB
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'filePath'
          filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test.ps1
          arguments: > # Use this to avoid newline characters in multiline string
            -Input1 $(key1)
            -Input2 $(wbKey)
            -Input3 ${{ parameters.param1 }}
        displayName: 'condition pattern 2'

## from wbKey:wbValue from vgtest
- stage: StageC
  condition: eq(variables.wbKey, 'wbValue')
  jobs:
  - job: JobC
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'filePath'
        filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test.ps1
        arguments: > # Use this to avoid newline characters in multiline string
          -Input1 $(key1)
          -Input2 $(wbKey)
          -Input3 ${{ parameters.param1 }}
      displayName: 'condition pattern 3'
```

`test.ps1`

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$Input1,
    [string]$Input2,
    [string]$Input3
)

Write-Output "test input from static variable $Input1"

Write-Output "test input from variable group $Input2"

Write-Output "test input from pipeline parameters $Input3"
```

Comment: But how to pass the value1 & wbValue as parameter to job , my job task is script it need some parameter values to start execution

Comment: Hi @pks, I have edit it. do this three patterns (may be one of them) suit for your case ? If anything more, comments out.